# Undocumented Wunderlist delete task-comment endpoint

Tags: wunderlist

There appears to be an endpoint on the Wunderlist API for deleting a task-comment which does not appear in the [official docs](https://developer.wunderlist.com/documentation/endpoints/task_comment)

Existing task comments can be deleted by sending a `DELETE` request to it, e.g. :

```
curl \
    -H "X-Access-Token: $WL_ACCESS_TOKEN" \
    -H "X-Client-ID: $WL_CLIENT_ID" \
    -XDELETE \
    https://a.wunderlist.com/api/v1/task_comments/12345?revision=1
```

Assuming the data is valid, this returns with `HTTP 204`.

Is this endpoint supported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is indeed an undocumented and unsupported API at this time.